# ASP.NET Trust Level

Tags: asp.net

Pessoal a Locaweb fez uma atualização nos servidores dela e um site de um cliente meu comecou a apresentar o seguinte erro:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permission...

Eles me sugeriram que alterasse o Trust Level para FULL.
Fui fazer isto no web.config assim:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web> 
      <trust level="Full" />
```

Ai o site comecou a apresentar o seguinte erro:`This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using <location allowOverride="false"> from an inherited configuration file.`

Como eu resolvo isto não entendo muito de ASP.NET.

Esté é o codigo do web.config do site.

```
<configuration>  <system.web>
<trust level="Full" />
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="100000" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<!--<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="GET" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="MSCaptcha.captchaImageHandler, MSCaptcha" />
</httpHandlers>-->
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Security, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".edmx" type="System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider" />
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
<authorization>
  <allow users="?" />
</authorization>
<roleManager enabled="true" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/administracao/login.aspx" name="frm_login" protection="All" timeout="2880" path="~/administracao" defaultUrl="~/administracao/default.aspx" />
</authentication>
<customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>  
<location path="administracao">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="administradores" />
    <!--<deny users="*"/>-->
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Acho que se eles definiram em um `.config` de nível superior que a config não pode ser sobrescrita (`allowOverride="false"`) não vai ter jeito, terá que pedir para o suporte deles permitir essa alteração  (`allowOverride="true"`)

Comment: Qual a versão do Windows Server?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez a versão é Windows 2008 - Enterprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como vocês viram não é possível alterar o `web.config` porque a *locaweb* não permite, então essa simples solução não funciona.

Verifiquem a versão da *DLL* do MySql que vocês estão usando, pois o problema é que as versões novas não funcionam com o `trust level medium`, então coloquei uma versão mais antiga e funcionou.

Estava usando a versão *6.7.4* e coloquei a *6.1.2* e parou de dar problema.

Comment: Fazer downgrade de bibliotecas não é uma boa solução, é no máximo um *workaround*.  Sua aplicação certamente perdeu bug fixes ou ganho de performance por conta do *downgrade*.

Answer (score 1):

[Segundo o Wiki da Locaweb](http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Security_Level_de_servidores_Windows_em_ambiente_dedicado), a configuração pode ser no máximo para **Medium Trust**:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web> 
      <trust level="Medium" /> 
      ...
   </system.web>
   ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Eu tentei o Medium também é da o mesmo erro. Já abri um chamado na Locaweb para ver se esta proibido de fazer a alteração no level, conforme o Marcus Vinicius citou acima.

Answer (score -2):

Recentemete descobri que para usar o arquivo .mdf disponibilizado pela microsoft tem que ser trust level full, o que a locaweb acaba impedindo o uso do mesmo.

E o jeito é mudar de hospedagem. Estou passando dor de cabeça por causa disso.

Segue um comentário abaixo:

To use an .mdf file you need to have the Full trust level (See [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/preparing-databases) for details, in the Entity Framework and Universal Providers section).

Your hosting provider does not allow you to change the trust level, so having the  directive causes the original error.

Removing the  directive the original error is resolved but then you get a security exception since your web application still requires the Full trust level to run, which your hosting provider does not provide.

Comment: Olá Arnaldo Junior, bem-vindo ao StackOverflowPT! Considere realizar comentários nos locais corretos! O seu comentário foi postado como uma resposta! Para postar um comentário, procure um link "comentar" abaixo das perguntas e respostas.