# Erro de Trust Level ao publicar aplicação MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp

Preciso publicar uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC num servidor da LocaWeb. Mas ao publicar, o servidor me exibe a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei colocar as tags

```
<securityPolicy>
  <trustLevel name="Medium" policyFile="web_mediumtrust.config" />
</securityPolicy>
<trust level="Full" originUrl="" />
```

Mas ao colocar, o servidor me retorna esta mensagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que devo fazer?

Comment: Estou postando como resposta por ainda não poder comentar. Veja essa questão [ASP.NET Trust Level](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64517/asp-net-trust-level) possui informações parecidas com as quais você forneceu.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [ASP.NET Trust Level](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64517/asp-net-trust-level)

Comment: Isso é algo da LocaWeb. [Essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70775/20615t) e [essa pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17637/20615) passaram pelo mesmo problema.

Comment: Eu já verifiquei estas perguntas e tentei tudo que está nelas, mas nada funcionou. Eu não estou utilizando nenhuma DLL externa. Já abri um chamado, mas eles informaram que eu deveria recompilar minha aplicação para funcionar em medium trust

Comment: Já verifiquei esta resposta, e tentei tudo que está nela, e nada.

Comment: É exatamente isso. Pode ser mais fácil trocar de hospedagem do que ajustar sua aplicação.

Comment: Mas esta é a única hospedagem que suporta o MVC e que seja boa que consegui encontrar. Tem alguma pra indicar ai?

Comment: Tem [essa](http://www.smarterasp.net/) que você pode testar durante 60 dias. [Esta outra](https://www.arvixe.com/) foi bem recomendada. Mas no geral mesmo, eu ainda acho o [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/) a melhor opção.